# Re-prompting after invalid input on second prompt in a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

Please bear with me as I may have a difficult time wording this.

I have a program that asks the user 2 questions.

"Enter the Subject"  --> user enters subject(i.e. CMIS)

"Enter the CatalogNbr"  --> user enters catalogNbr(i.e. 300)

If a user doesn't enter anything for the first prompt, it says "A Subject is required" and then the loop goes back and asks the question again(Expected). Once a valid input is accepted, it goes onto the 2nd prompt. Now when the second prompt is left blank, the loop goes to the postQuery message ("Would you like to try again? Y/N"). But when I put 'continue' after the bottom of the if not method(in the second prompt) it says "A CatalogNbr is required" but then reverts back to the beginning of the loop (prompt number one).

In short, I know there is something wrong with my while loop here but I can't figure it out. I tried to add a second while loop but I've been hung up on this for hours and I know I'm just missing something small here and it's driving me crazy. Anyways, enough rambling. Here's what I got:

```
while True:
subjectName = input("Enter the Subject:")
if not subjectName.isupper():
    print("A Subject is required")
    continue


catNum=input("Enter the CatalogNbr:")   
if not catNum:
    print("A CatalogNbr is required.")
```

and here's my postQuery

```
postQuery=input("Would you like to search for another title? (Y or N)")

if postQuery == 'N':
    print("Thanks for using the Catalog Search program.")
    break
```

Comment: do you want to proceed if the user doesn't enter CatalogNbr ? As per your code, it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with the below code. It is working as expected. The subject is mandatory and CatalogNbr is optional.

```
while True:
    subjectName = input("Enter the Subject:")
    if not subjectName :
        print("A Subject is required")
        continue

    catNum=input("Enter the CatalogNbr:")
    if not catNum:
        print("A CatalogNbr is required.")

    postQuery = input("Would you like to search for another title? (Y or N)")

    if postQuery == 'N':
        print("Thanks for using the Catalog Search program.")
        break
```